# Zero rates coupon bond calculation

Tags: zero-coupon

In order to do cash flow mapping I need zero rates for corporate bonds , where to find or how to find the o rates ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a topic that can be covered by an entire book... Typically, you select some liquid instruments such as swaps, deposits, futures etc etc to bootstrap a yield curve, from which you can use it for discounting. The problem is not how to bootstrap, but what to bootstrap. It's a very complicated issue, you may have to consider cost of funding, liquidity, maturity etc.

Please read: [A Practical Guide to Swap Curve Construction](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/wp00-17.pdf), you can find it on Google.

Comment: This is the right approach, but I wouldn't recommend this specific paper. This kind of swap construction technique (LIBOR discounting) is no longer correct in the post financial crisis world.

Comment: Do you mean multi-curve and OIS discounting? I think this should be step that the poster should attempt later on. The paper I quote is dead simple for someone to get started.

Comment: that's a fair point. I just wanted to make sure OIS discounting is eventually mentioned here.